# How can I send pre-filled text via Facebook Messenger web interface using Next.js?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

How to send **pre-filled text** via **Facebook Messenger** web interface using Next.js?

I'm working on a Next.js application and I'm trying to implement a feature where users can send pre-filled text messages to their friends via Facebook Messenger. I want to provide a button that, when clicked, opens the Facebook Messenger web interface with the text field pre-filled with a specific message.

I have tried using the URL scheme **https://www.messenger.com/t/?text=My%20pre-filled%20text**, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Instead, it opens messenger.com but there wasn't the pre-filled text.

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this functionality using Next.js and the Facebook Messenger web interface. Are there any specific API endpoints or SDKs that I should be using? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: prefilling is not allowed, and not possible. all text must be 100% user generated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send prefilled message to FB messenger only if the recipient is a business page.

Once button clicked, you can `window.open(http://m.me/PAGE-NAME?text=Hello%20and%20Welcome)`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links/